# Is it possible to include HTML in a petition introduction?

Tags: civipetiton, editor

When I include HTML formatting in a petition "Introduction" field, it passes through to the front end petition view as displayed text, rather than being interpreted as formatting instructions.  This happens in:

4.6.8 with textarea editing
4.7.1 with ckeditor or textarea

Am I missing something?  Or is this just not a supported feature?

Comment: I just tried in 4.6.13 and it just works. Can you repeat what you did in https://civicrm.org/demo ?

Comment: I tried to test on the demo site, but it gives a permission error when I try to display the petition for signature, and I don't have access to edit Joomla permissions.

I did just test 4.6.8 with ckeditor, and that works if I use "source" mode.  So maybe this is just a bug with 4.7.1's ckeditor, which I can't get to interpret the HTML whether in Source mode or not.